# How to prevent stopping a macro on unsuccessful substitution?

Tags: substitute, macro

I've been trying to record a rather simple macro with two substitutions. The whole macro is: `dd"+pkdd:%s/\t/, /g
:%s/ \(kb\d\+\),/ \1.0,/g
"+y$`

However, the second substitution is there to reformat numbers from a format `123` to `123.0` but the input does not always need the substitution so it fails. When it fails the whole macro stops so the last part (`"+y$`) does not execute.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured it out thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093959/how-do-i-disable-error-messages-when-a-substitution-fails-inside-a-vim-function). One needs to put an `e` flag to the substitution so the substitution looks like this: `:%s/ \(kb\d\+\),/ \1.0,/ge`. `e` suppresses the error message and lets the macro finish.